# OpenSSL in QT Creator doesn't works -- How to setup correctly?

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, cryptography

**I'm totally desperate. I'm trying to use OpenSSL, but I can't install/implement it correctly and I have no Errorcode. What I did:**

I downloaded OpenSSL from Softpedia, Version 1.1.0J, X64 and installed everything into a folder. I installed the Binarys (dll) in the /bin folder.

After that I added this commands to QT creator .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Users\Martin\Downloads\OpenSSL-Win64"
LIBS += -LC:\Users\Martin\Downloads\OpenSSL-Win64\lib -llibcrypto
```

And then I tried to use the PBKDF2 funtion, including 
But it isn't working :( The Program crashes or isn't doing anything...  Code for PBKDF2 is here:

```
char    pass[] = "try";
unsigned char salt[] = "salt232";
char salt1[] = "salt232";
int iter = 1000,
    keylen = 32,
    saltlen = sizeof(salt1),
    passlen = sizeof(pass);

unsigned char out[32];


PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(pass, passlen, salt, saltlen, iter, EVP_sha256(), keylen, out);
```

Little second question by the way: Why do we even have to build the .lib files? Why is OpenSSL not just using a standard Header and C++/C file like other librarys do?

QT Version: 4.8.2

OS: Windows 10, X64

Coding level: beginner

emotional state: helpless to desperate, maybe I'll have to search for
   another library...

Comment: I'd just build it from source, rather than fight with someone elses pre-built binaries, that might not even be built with a compatible compiler.

Comment: Yea, this might be better, but I think it's easier and I could make less mistakes.

Comment: By building it yourself you know it's built with a compatible compiler (the same as used for the rest of your code). It's really not that difficult. There are good instructions in the source repository.

Comment: OK, thank you :) I'll informate myselfe and try to do that.

Comment: The library situation on Windows is a bit more complex, than on Linux for example, even for C libraries. The library really needs to be compatible with the Qt version (including bittiness, toolchain, and even some build options).